# music21 : to create a midi file with snare and bass drums at the same offset

Tags: python, music21

I am trying to create a midi file using music21 (v6.5.0 and Python 3.8.6) for a drums track. I am unable to create a stream with two sounds at the same offset (say the bass and the snare).

```
snareNote = Note('C')
bassFirstNote = Note('C', quarterLength=2)
bassSecondNote = Note('C', quarterLength=2)
hiHatNote = Note('C')

musicStream = stream.Stream()
streamMeasure = stream.Measure()
streamMeasure.timeSignature = meter.TimeSignature('4/4')
musicStream.append(streamMeasure)

snarePart = stream.Part()
# snarePart.insert(createInstrumentWithChannel(instrument.SnareDrum(), 1))
snareDrum = instrument.SnareDrum()
snareDrum.midiChannel = 1
snarePart.insert(snareDrum)

bassPart = stream.Part()
# bassPart.insert(createInstrumentWithChannel(instrument.BassDrum(), 2))
bassDrum = instrument.BassDrum()
bassDrum.midiChannel = 2
bassPart.insert(bassDrum)
bassPart.append(bassFirstNote)
bassPart.append(bassSecondNote)
musicStream.insert(0, bassPart)

hiHatPart = stream.Part()
# hiHatPart.insert(createInstrumentWithChannel(instrument.HiHatCymbal(), 3))
hiHat = instrument.HiHatCymbal()
hiHat.midiChannel = 3
hiHatPart.insert(hiHat)
hiHatPart.repeatAppend(hiHatNote, 4)
musicStream.insert(0, hiHatPart)

musicStream.show('text')
musicStream.write('midi', fp='drums.mid')
```

My text output shows the bass and hihat notes at the right offsets - however the midi output contains only the last part that I am inserting into the stream (in this case the hihat).

```
{0.0} <music21.stream.Measure 0 offset=0.0>
    {0.0} <music21.meter.TimeSignature 4/4>
{0.0} <music21.stream.Part 0x1a993ca5d00>
    {0.0} <music21.instrument.BassDrum 'Bass Drum'>
    {0.0} <music21.note.Note C>
    {2.0} <music21.note.Note C>
{0.0} <music21.stream.Part 0x1a993cbe100>
    {0.0} <music21.instrument.HiHatCymbal 'Hi-Hat Cymbal'>
    {0.0} <music21.note.Note C>
    {1.0} <music21.note.Note C>
    {2.0} <music21.note.Note C>
    {3.0} <music21.note.Note C>
```

Comment: Could you articulate the example without your custom function `createInstrumentWithChannel`? Thanks.

Comment: Thank you, Jacob. Have edited the example to expand the createInstrumentWithChannel() inline so that there isn't any custom functions.

Appreciate your help.

Comment: Hello Jacob - When I change the notes to be the midi drum notes (i.e. 38 for an acoustic snare, 35 for an acoustic bass and 42 for a closed hi hat), I get the desired result. 
Earlier, when I set all the notes to a 'C' and set them, my midi file had just the final notes that I had added to the stream.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the code to use the right notes seem to have solved the problem. Instead of using a 'C' note for all the drums notes, using the right drum midi notes addressed the issue.

***Incorrect:***

```
snareNote = Note('C')
bassFirstNote = Note('C', quarterLength=2)
bassSecondNote = Note('C', quarterLength=2)
hiHatNote = Note('C')
```

***Correct:***

```
snareNote = Note(38)
bassFirstNote = Note(35, quarterLength=2)
bassSecondNote = Note(35, quarterLength=2)
hiHatNote = Note(42)
```